# Jquery - Change Background position on 1st click, reset on the 2nd

Tags: jquery, background-position

Evening all! I have half a script that I need to change the CSS background position of an element when it is clicked - this works fine. However I need the CSS to reset the background position to 0 0 on the 2nd click;

Help much appreciated!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#login-btn').click(function(){
                $('#login-btn').css('backgroundPosition', '0px -39px');
                 }, function(){
                $('$login-btn').css('backgroundPosition', '0px 0px');

             });
            });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd put the CSS in a class, and use `.toggleClass()`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xwnKP/

```
$('#login-btn').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

*css*

```
#login-btn {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
#login-btn.clicked {
    background-position: 0 -39px;
}
```

If you wanted to do it the way you had it, you need to change from `click()` [to `toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/), which is like click except that accepts more than one function argument.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xwnKP/1/

```
$('#login-btn').toggle(function() {
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0px -39px');
    }, function() {
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '0px 0px');
});
```